# Which font is used in this Wordpress image?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image]

I updated WordPress to the latest version and this image (the website [https://wordpress.org/news/2023/03/dolphy](https://wordpress.org/news/2023/03/dolphy/)) and I'd like to know what font is this. It seems Inter but I am not sure.

Comment: If you can open the webpage in Chrome or Firefox, then you can right click an element and inspect it, then check the CSS and to see what font it is. The webpage you linked to uses Inter for the body text.  Images have no font information though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **any** web site, all one needs to so is merely look at the style sheet....

https://wordpress.org/news/wp-content/mu-plugins/pub-sync/global-fonts/style.css?ver=1675219904

Courier Prime
Inter
EB Garamond
IBM Plex Mono

Comment: Yes, it seems Inter! Thanks!